# Delete lines in a file by piping search pattern into Sed

Tags: unix, sed, grep, aix

Is there anyway we can delete lines in a file like below.

grep {SearchPattern} {file} | cut -c 1-9 | Sed {file}

Whatever I am searching can actually occur fewer than lines I want to delete.
I want to actually search and take first 9 char and search again and delete whatever lines come in output.

my input file would like as below .

```
0002206993022      Enrollment Status             Terminated                              08/01/201412/31/9999 
0003119343022      Enrollment Status             Terminated                              05/28/201512/31/9999
0003119343009999   Pay Status                    N/A                                     09/10/201405/28/2015
```

you can I would to search for all "Terminated" persons and take their IDs by taking first 9 digits in the first column. I would like to delete all of their records be it Pay Status or Enrollment Status or whatever

Comment: Please provide proper input data and output data.

Comment: @Mark, does that help? Can you please answer now.

Comment: That's the input. What about the output?

Comment: Output is mentioned , I want to delete all lines of terminated persons.

Comment: Sorry, it is still very unclear, to me at least, what you want.

Comment: How does `grep -v Terminated file` not produce the end result you want? (For improved precision, `awk -F '\t' '$3 != "Terminated"' file`.)

Comment: I think OPS wants to find ID's of all terminated persons and delete all records (also `Pay Status`)  starting with the found IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
awk '/Terminated/{$0=substr($0, 1, 9);print "^" $0}' file | grep -vf - file
```

**Update:**

Try (Non `GNU` grep):

```
awk '/Terminated/{$0=substr($0, 1, 9);print "^" $0}' file | grep -vf /dev/stdin file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file
0002206993022      Enrollment Status             Terminated                              08/01/201412/31/9999 
0003119343022      Enrollment Status             Terminated                              05/28/201512/31/9999
0003119343009999   Pay Status                    N/A                                     09/10/201405/28/2015
1003119343009999   Pay Status                    N/A                                     09/10/201405/28/2015

$ awk '/Terminated/{$0=substr($0, 1, 9);print "^" $0}' file | grep -vf - file
1003119343009999   Pay Status                    N/A                                     09/10/201405/28/2015
```

Comment: Excellant, but unfortunately that "-" for sysin doesnt work in AIX.                      I am getting below error.                                                                                               "grep: can't open -"

Comment: Thanks for that, I need to find out path of stdin in my OS. I checked /bin/stdin, /etc/stdin, /dev/stdin.

Comment: @Ahmad, Try: `/proc/self/fd/0`

Comment: @Ahmad, Or Try : `grep -vf <(awk '/Terminated/{$0=substr($0, 1, 9);print "^" $0}' file) file`